# How to work out the expected value of $X^3$ for a geometric distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, geometric-distribution

I have scoured all my textbooks and all through the internet but haven't been able to find a suitable answer to this. I have struggled my way through finding the expected value of $X^2$, with the help of Google, but I am utterly lost with this one. 
[image]

This image ^ shows how I worked out E(X^2) and how I tried to start working out E(X^3), but I'm really confused now!

Cheers and TIA for helping me :)

Comment: Also called the second moment, see http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfd-geometric.htm

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did you calculate the first and second moments? In the future, please include the self-study tag on homework problems.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, will keep that in mind. I actually haven't heard of moments in this context before but I have had a look at the link you have sent. I'll attach my working for E(x^2)

Comment: Do you know why you throw the $x(x-1)$ in front of $P(X=x)$ in the infinite sum?

Comment: Yes? I think we do that as we are multiplying that by the probability of obtaining that; we're finding E(X(X-1)).

Comment: When we want to find the expected value of a transformation, we stick that transformation out in front. This is why the $x$ is out in front of the calculation of the mean (the identity transformation). Now what happens if you have the cubic transformation $x^3$ instead of $x^2-x=x(x-1)$?

Comment: please check this $EX^2 = VarX + E^2X = \frac{1-p}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^2} = \frac{2-p}{p^2}$

Comment: Hint: $x^3 = x(x-1)(x-2) + 3x(x-1) + x$ and you already have the expectations of $X(X-1)$ and $X.$

Comment: Thank you all so much! Yes, I did spot that error in my working and have sorted that out. That hint is super helpful - it's 1am now haha but I am going to try to work that out asap and will reach out if I'm still stuck. Honestly, thank you all so much!

Comment: This is the variant of the geom dist'n implemented in R. Two ways to do reality check of your answ for $p=1/3:$ (a) Sum huge nr of terms in series, R code `k=0:10000; pdf=dgeom(k,1/3); sum(k*pdf)` returns 2; `sum(k^3*pdf)` returns 74. (b) Simulate,  `mean(rgeom(10^7, p)^3)` returns 74.01668.

Comment: I am unable to work out the expected value of $X(X-1)(X-2)$ and even tried a different factorisation of X^3 as  X^3=X(X^2−1)+X to no avail. Could someone please help?